# How to divide an ee.image into small images of size 256 x 256 x bandas?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I have an huge image in a rectangle geometry and I want to divide this image into m images of size 256x256 with all its bands. If I merge all the images, I will get the original image and in order to get images with 256x256, some 256x256 images can have parts of another 256x256 image. How can I do this in the google earth engine?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified, but I assume you want to tile the image for processing outside of Earth Engine. If that is the case, you can simply specify  `fileDimensions` when exporting to Drive:

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: image, 
  folder: 'tiled-export',
  description: 'large-image', 
  scale: 30, 
  fileDimensions: 256
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/84c18407f35513a1f5aba4aa640871a2

Comment: I want to use this image outside earth engine indeed. But I have tried this approach and the dimensions output are not exact 256 for all images, I tried to use this in an image of shape 257x256 and I end up exporting two images, one with 256x256 as I want it and other one with 1x256 and I want all of my images with shape 256x256